# Is there a way to know which position text overflow occurred in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, dart, widget, overflow

I have several text boxes of different widths sequentially in one of my layouts, and I need to know where overflow occurred in a Text widget so the next Text widget can pick up where the last one left off.

Been looking around in the documentation for a way to check wherein a Text widget an overflow occurred, but haven't been able to find anything. Is this possible at this point?

Comment: can u pls share some code?

Comment: Flutter's low-level text layout capabilities leave a bit to be desired. Your best bet is to try and figure something out using [`TextPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html), though any solution will probably be a bit involved.

Comment: @AR I'd share it if I had any to share, that's the issue.